# Google Sheets API returns null for inputValue

Tags: .net, google-api, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the formula out of a cell not the final value

```
// A1  www.google.com
// B1 =A1

cell.inputValue // value is null. I want the value: =A1
cell.value // equals www.google.com. Again not the value I'm looking for.
```

According to googles API documentation the formula is suppose to be in the inputValue property

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#working_with_cell-based_feeds

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the basic URL does not contain the inputValue formula.

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/spreadsheetId/worksheetId/private/values

you have to use full projection to get the hydrated properties.

```
CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(key, "od6", "private", "full");
```